# Legal rights of replicants?

Tags: blade-runner-2049

It appears that replicants can live on Earth and move freely but one needs permission. The hookers (owned by a human "pimp"?) can ply their trade. I guess Sapper Morton was a prohibited model? (The hooker asks K if he will kill her and he replies, iirc, it depends what model number you are.)

I do not know what the legal protection enslaved people had in the south -- if it was illegal to murder your own slave, I suspect that the owner was rarely prosecuted and if you killed someone else's slave, I bet you owed them the value of the slave.

I would guess that replicants has even less protection. In one of the short films made before BR-2049 came out, Wallace commands his servant to commit suicide. The people witnessing this were not very happy about it but no one discussed legal prosecution for what was in effect murder -- I think they objected to the replicant itself but Wallace was demoing a "safe" replicant so that he could I guess sell them on Earth.

Comment: Replicants have no legal rights because they're not slaves, they're replicants. They are, however, property, which means that you can't just go round killing or damaging them, any more than you can wilfully damage a car

Comment: @Valorum: although you can damage your *own* car.

Comment: Indeed. And Wallace uses that principle to great effect in proving that his new model replicants are little more than biological robots. What he refers to as "disposable"

Comment: @Valorum: and having no legal rights they can only operate among humans secretly by pretending to be humans or openly (as the doxies do) and so i suspect they are owned by a human. on the other hand, maybe there is an underworld which exists much like the dark web, where replicants are even known to exist but are winked at as long as they cause no trouble. I am interested in how replicant hookers survive among humans and whether large number of replicants live semi-openly among humans.